# Firestore orderBy descending is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

When using Firestore I get an error only when I use .orderBy 
error message is: 
Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: [FirebaseError: no matching index found.]

```
todoRef
      .where("owner", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .where("date", "==", props.date)
      .orderBy("description", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const data = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const d = {
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          };
          data.push(d);
        });
        //console.log("coming from function", data);
        setData(data);
        return data;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

**ANDROID**
On your terminal type:

> adb logcat

or open logcat on Android studio, you will find a log with the error, reporting the url to create automatically the index required.

**IOS**
Open xCode, go to logs and you will find a log with error, reporting the url to create automatically the index required.

If the url doesn't show, it's a known bug on firebase sdk. Follow this issue to get any update:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152

If you don't want to wait just create manually the index with the console.

Comment: RemindLive[7126:555467] [javascript] 'Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:', { [FirebaseError: no matching index found.]
  code: 'failed-precondition',
  name: 'FirebaseError',
  toString: [Function] }

Comment: Are you using android or iOS? Did you follow the steps?

Comment: Yes I followed but I don't see any urls

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the index in your firebase console. Copy the link that has been printed into the console.

Comment: RemindLive[7126:555467] [javascript] 'Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:', { [FirebaseError: no matching index found.]
  code: 'failed-precondition',
  name: 'FirebaseError',
  toString: [Function] }